# What's the maximum magnetic field a electron can generate?, What the max for a proton?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, electrons, protons, subatomic

I actually have multiple questions, What's the maximum magnetic field an electron can generate?, What the max for a proton? Is there a limit to how powerful a magnetic field you can generate with a single charged particle.

Comment: I imagine you would run into issues with pair production (or production of other particles due to interactions at high energies) at some point but am not sure if that is the limiting factor.